# Filter by multiple nested properties

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index definition like this:

```json
    {
      "settings": {
        "index": {
          "number_of_shards": 1,
          "number_of_replicas": 0
        },
      },
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "parameters_for_filter": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "parameters": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "parameter_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "parameter_value_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the exported result for one product:

```json
    {
      "_index": "product_1_9107bbdeb03269e1142d9822e585008c",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "69",
      "_version": 1,
      "_score": 0,
      "_source": {
        "id": 69,
        "parameters_for_filter": {
          "parameters": [
            [
              {
                "parameter_id": 5,
                "parameter_value_id": 10
              },
              {
                "parameter_id": 3,
                "parameter_value_id": 251
              },
              {
                "parameter_id": 1,
                "parameter_value_id": 248
              }
            ],
            [
              {
                "parameter_id": 5,
                "parameter_value_id": 16
              },
              {
                "parameter_id": 3,
                "parameter_value_id": 251
              },
              {
                "parameter_id": 1,
                "parameter_value_id": 254
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Another product:

```json
{
  "_index": "product_1_9107bbdeb03269e1142d9822e585008c",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "83",
  "_version": 5,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "id": 83,
    "parameters_for_filter": {
      "parameters": [
        [
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 10,
            "parameter_id": 5
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 251,
            "parameter_id": 3
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 254,
            "parameter_id": 1
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 16,
            "parameter_id": 5
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 121,
            "parameter_id": 2
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 254,
            "parameter_id": 1
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Each sub-array inside `parameters_for_filter.parameters` represents parameters of individual variants of a product.

What I need to do is get the product with ID 69 for combination of filters:

`{{parameter_id: 5, parameter_value_id: 10}, {parameter_id: 1, parameter_value_id: 248}}`.

Get the product with ID 83 for combination of filters:

`{{parameter_id: 5, parameter_value_id: 10}, {parameter_id: 1, parameter_value_id: 254}}`.

Get both products for combination of filters:

`{{parameter_id: 5, parameter_value_id: 16}, {parameter_id: 1, parameter_value_id: 254}}`.

Get no products for combination of filters:

`{{parameter_id: 5, parameter_value_id: 16}, {parameter_id: 1, parameter_value_id: 248}}`.

With current query I get the product with all 3 above combinations:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_id": 5
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_value_id": [
                        10
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_id": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_value_id": [
                        248
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What would the filter that would accomplish what I need look like or is there a better structure that I could use for parameters of product variants in eshop (without exporting variants as separate objects)?

Comment: So you'd like to explicitly exclude `{{parameter_id: 5, parameter_value_id: 10}, {parameter_id: 1, parameter_value_id: 254}}` or all combinations that don't fulfil the 2 either/or combinations?

Comment: The second option is correct. I only want to get the result if both of those parameters and their values are contained in one of the sub-arrays of `parameters_for_filter`.

Comment: OK can you include a few more sample docs that should not match? I mean, under the current query, I'd expect the whole parent doc to be returned b/c both conditions are present in _some_ of the `parameters`. Also, are you familiar with inner hits in nested docs? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html#search-request-inner-hits ?

Comment: I added one more product and desired returned values. I want the parent to be returned so that is not the problem. I looked at inner hits but cannot really understand how I could use them in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've somehow got to let ES know that the `parameters` are indeed distinct groups of attributes and upon closer inspection it appear that there's one extra bracket `[ ]` pair enclosing the params which essentially nullifies the nested-ness b/c everything is one large array.

What I propose is the following: since `parameters_for_filter` is an object consisting of precisely 1 child, we'll default it to a simple `object` and we'll add one more level of nested-ness to isolate what I'll call `parameter_groups`.
So the mapping'll look like this:

```
PUT eshop
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "parameters_for_filter": {
        "type": "object",                <--
        "properties": {
          "parameters": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "parameter_groups": {      <---
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "parameter_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "parameter_value_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that let's sync the 2 docs. Notice how the param groups are logically separated:

```
POST eshop/_doc
{
  "id": 69,
  "parameters_for_filter": {
    "parameters": [
      {
        "parameter_groups": [
          {
            "parameter_id": 5,
            "parameter_value_id": 10
          },
          {
            "parameter_id": 3,
            "parameter_value_id": 251
          },
          {
            "parameter_id": 1,
            "parameter_value_id": 248
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parameter_groups": [
          {
            "parameter_id": 5,
            "parameter_value_id": 16
          },
          {
            "parameter_id": 3,
            "parameter_value_id": 251
          },
          {
            "parameter_id": 1,
            "parameter_value_id": 254
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and also `id:83`

```
POST eshop/_doc
{
  "id": 83,
  "parameters_for_filter": {
    "parameters": [
      {
        "parameter_groups": [
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 10,
            "parameter_id": 5
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 251,
            "parameter_id": 3
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 254,
            "parameter_id": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parameter_groups": [
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 16,
            "parameter_id": 5
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 121,
            "parameter_id": 2
          },
          {
            "parameter_value_id": 254,
            "parameter_id": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After that we'll proceed to the query which'll look for a `must` combination of the two condition, albeit under separate `parameter_groups` paths:

```
GET eshop/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_groups",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_groups.parameter_id": 5
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_groups.parameter_value_id": [
                            16
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_groups",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_groups.parameter_id": 1
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_groups.parameter_value_id": [
                            248
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All 4 of your requirements are thereby satisfied.

Comment: We're still testing but it looks really promising and I'll definitely let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result (used the same mapping as that given in question)

You can use the `filter` clause, in place of the `must` clause, if you want to ignore the scoring

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": 69,
  "parameters_for_filter": {
    "parameters": [
      [
        {
          "parameter_id": 5,
          "parameter_value_id": 10
        },
        {
          "parameter_id": 3,
          "parameter_value_id": 251
        },
        {
          "parameter_id": 1,
          "parameter_value_id": 254
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
{
  "id": 69,
  "parameters_for_filter": {
    "parameters": [
      [
        {
          "parameter_id": 5,
          "parameter_value_id": 10
        },
        {
          "parameter_id": 3,
          "parameter_value_id": 251
        },
        {
          "parameter_id": 1,
          "parameter_value_id": 248
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
{
  "id": 69,
  "parameters_for_filter": {
    "parameters": [
      [
        {
          "parameter_id": 5,
          "parameter_value_id": 10
        },
        {
          "parameter_id": 3,
          "parameter_value_id": 251
        },
        {
          "parameter_id": 1,
          "parameter_value_id": 247
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_id": 5
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_value_id": 10
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_id": 1
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_value_id": 248
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_id": 5
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_value_id": 16
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "parameters_for_filter.parameters",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_id": 1
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "parameters_for_filter.parameters.parameter_value_id": 254
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64678935",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 4.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 69,
          "parameters_for_filter": {
            "parameters": [
              [
                {
                  "parameter_id": 5,
                  "parameter_value_id": 10
                },
                {
                  "parameter_id": 3,
                  "parameter_value_id": 251
                },
                {
                  "parameter_id": 1,
                  "parameter_value_id": 248
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem with this is that the data can't very well look like this. That object with ID 69 is a product. It has some variants and those variants have each their own parameters. We need to find a product that has a variant which matches all the selected parameters. We can change the format of those parameters within the exported product object but we don't want to export variants as individual objects.

Comment: @LukášKielar if you index the same sample index document (that you have added in the question), and run the above search query, you will get your required search result (I have already tested it locally). Please try to run the search query once, with your data as well, and let me know if now your issue is resolved :)

Comment: Well, it seems to work for this particular query but if I wanted to filter exactly like this it would look like `{{"parameter_id": 5, "parameter_value_id": [10, 16]}, {"parameter_id": 1, "parameter_value_id": [248, 254]}}`. Both parameters need to be present but there would be OR between their values. If I use your solution for `{{parameter_id: 5, parameter_value_id: 16}, {parameter_id: 1, parameter_value_id: 248}}` it still returns product even though I don't expect any.